# How to assign dataframes to specific locations in a list in R

Tags: r, list, variable-assignment, paste

I've created 15 individual dataframes via a for loop, each one representing scores for each of the survey items comprising 15 different scales/topic areas. They're named df1 through df15 based on the original order of my topic areas, but I'd like to put them into a single list based on a different sort order. I have a separate dataframe, called topic.area, listing each of the 15 topic areas, their original order, and it is arranged in the new sort order:

Topic.Area......  orig.order...  sort.order
Leadership........3................1
Engagement.....      1              ...............2
Innovation.........2................3
etc...

I essentially want to do the following, but the code isn't working for me. I'm very new to R, so I appreciate any solutions that aren't too advanced so I understand the logic behind them.

```
myList<- list()

for(m in 1:15) {
 myList[[m]]<- paste("df", topic.area$orig.order[m], sep = "") 
}
```

I think the issue is you can't use the paste function in an assignment command, but I don't know to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the dataframe in a list. As you have mentioned this is already ordered by `orig.order`.

```
list_df <- mget(paste0('df', 1:15))
```

You can arrange them based on `sort.order` directly by doing :

```
sorted_list_df <- list_df[topic.area$sort.order]
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work. The first part of the code put in extra dataframes since I had other objects that had "df" plus a number in the name, so the length of the list is 30. Then the second part of the code left everything but the first two list objects as null.

Comment: I got the first part to work by putting a ^ in front of the "df" (I had other objects with df# in them), but the sort isn't working. It goes from 1 to 10-15, then 2-9.

Comment: First check if `list_df` has the same order as present in `orig.order`.

Comment: if you're using a loop to create the data frames, you'll want to add leading zeros between `df` and the number to create the right original sort order. `df10` sorts before `df2` in an alphanumeric sort.  You can use `sprintf("df%02i",i)` in a `for(i in 1:15)` loop to generate names that will sort in numerical order.

Comment: OP posted `They're named df1 through df15 based on the original order of my topic areas`. So I think they are already ordered based on `orig.order`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely reproducible example based on [Pokémon Stats](https://github.com/lgreski/pokemonData) data. Instead of just writing the input files to a `list()`, I use `assign()` to simulate a set of data frames in the global environment.

```
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/pokemonData.zip",
              "pokemonData.zip",
              method="curl",mode="wb")
unzip("pokemonData.zip")

thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokemonData",
                              full.names=TRUE)
filenames <- substr(list.files("./pokemonData",full.names = FALSE),1,5) 
results <- lapply(1:length(thePokemonFiles),function(x) {
     # read data and assign to a name in global environment 
     data <- read.csv(thePokemonFiles[x],stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
     assign(filenames[x],data,globalenv())
     return(TRUE)
})
```

At this point we have 7 data frames named `gen01` to `gen07` in the global environment.

[image]

Next, we generate the desired sort order as a vector. We'll use this along with the names from the `filenames` vector to get the data and build the output list in the desired sort order of data frames.

```
desiredSortOrder <- c(1,3,5,7,2,4,6)
sortedDataFrames <- lapply(desiredSortOrder,function(x){
     get(filenames[x])
})
# verify generation numbers by printing first row of each data frame 
lapply(sortedDataFrames,function(x){
     x[1,c(1,2,12)]
})
```

Since the `Generation` column in each data frame matches its associated file name, we can verify the sort order by printing the first row of each data frame.

```
>lapply(sortedDataFrames,function(x){
+      x[1,c(1,2,12)]
+ })
[[1]]
  Number      Name Generation
1      1 Bulbasaur          1

[[2]]
  Number    Name Generation
1    252 Treecko          3

[[3]]
  Number    Name Generation
1    494 Victini          5

[[4]]
  Number   Name Generation
1    722 Rowlet          7

[[5]]
  Number      Name Generation
1    152 Chikorita          2

[[6]]
  Number    Name Generation
1    387 Turtwig          4

[[7]]
  Number    Name Generation
1    650 Chespin          6

>
```